# How to embed an exe file into another exe file as a resource in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd, resources, exe

I am trying to use a pre-build .exe file as a resource in my C++ project, after searching I done the following steps:

**Step1**
Create a new C++ project and place the following code in the *Source.cpp* file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<fstream>
#define IDB_EMBEDEXE 52
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int count = 2;

    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_EMBEDEXE), __TEXT("BINARY"));
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(NULL, hResource);
    size_t exeSiz = SizeofResource(NULL, hResource);
    void* exeBuf = LockResource(hGlobal);

    ofstream outfile((char*)exeBuf, ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!outfile)
        exit(9);
    outfile.write((char*)exeBuf, exeSiz);
    system((char*)exeBuf);

    return 0;
}
```

***Step2*** Create a new resource file (.rc)
1- *Project>Add new item*
2- From *Installed>Visual C++>Resource* choose *Resource File (.rc)* let us name it *Resource.rc*

***Step3*** Edit the header file *resource.h* that has just created from Step2, add the following line to the header file:
`#define IDB_EMBEDEXE 52`

***Step4*** Edit the *Resource.rc* file by right click on it>Open with>Source Code (Text) Editor, add the following code just after the first `#include` statment (i.e. after `#include "resource.h"`

```
#define IDB_EMBEDEXE 52
IDB_EMBEDEXE    BINARY      "C:\\Users\\Almohandis\\source\\repos\\Project7\\sum2num.exe"
```

After doing exactly these steps, I still get the following error in the cmd (not in the Visual Studio):

> 'MZ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

And the program ends with code 0

I think calling `system()` what causes the problem, especially the argument I passed.

**Note that** the binary representation of the *sum2num.exe* file starts with `MZ....`

Comment: You seem to be confusing the path of an executable file with the content of an executable file. The constructor of an `std::ostream` object requires the path of the output file, not its content. The same applies to `system`. Also, you should close the file before attempting to execute it.

Comment: If your `#define` is already in `resource.h`, there is no need to duplicate it in your source files. Just use `#include "resource.h"` in the code instead. In any case, you should be using the pre-defined `RCDATA` resource type, instead of creating a custom `BINARY` type.

Comment: Have you considered using an *Installer* instead?  An Installer application installs your executable, and *any dependencies*.

Answer (score 2):

If your `#define` is already in `resource.h`, there is no need to duplicate it in your source code. Just use `#include "resource.h"` in your code instead.

In any case, you should be using the pre-defined `RCDATA` resource type, instead of creating a custom `BINARY` type.

That being said, your use of `ofstream` and `system()` are both wrong.  You are passing them the resource's raw binary data, but they are expecting a file path instead.  You are using a file path in your `.rc` file to specify the file whose binary data is copied into the resource.  The resource does not contain that file path, as you are clearly expecting.

Try this instead:

resource.h

```
...
#define IDB_EMBEDEXE 52
...
```

Resource.rc

```
#include "resource.h"
...
IDB_EMBEDEXE    RCDATA      "C:\\Users\\Almohandis\\source\\repos\\Project7\\sum2num.exe"
...
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include "resource.h"
using namespace std;
        
int main() {

    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_EMBEDEXE), RT_RCDATA);
    if (!hResource)
        return 1;

    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(NULL, hResource);
    if (!hGlobal)
        return 2;

    DWORD exeSiz = SizeofResource(NULL, hResource);
    if (!exeSiz)
        return 3;

    void* exeBuf = LockResource(hGlobal);
    if (!exeBuf)
        return 4;

    char tempPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    if (!GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, path))
        return 5;

    string fullPath = string(tempPath) + "sum2num.exe";

    ofstream outfile(fullPath.c_str(), ios::binary);
    if (!outfile.is_open())
        return 6;

    int res = (outfile.write((char*)exeBuf, exeSiz)) ? 0 : 7;
    outfile.close();

    if (res == 0) {
        system(fullPath.c_str());
    }

    remove(fullPath.c_str());

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine on my laptop, but when I copied the generated .exe file and run it on another laptop it doesn' work, why? My original purpose is to make it work on any machine though.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElmohandes What EXACTLY is not working? You need to be more specific, there are a lot of failure points in this approach. Is the target EXE not being embedded in the resource? Is the code not able to find the resource? Not able to access the resource? Not able to create the output file? Not able to write the resource data to the file? Not able to execute the file?

Comment: The error says that some .dll files are missing, but I did not embed any .dll files!
Should I install VS on the other laptop? If so, then that is not what I wanted, I want to give this final .exe file to anyone and they will be able to run it without any installation of any programs.

Comment: "*The error says that some .dll files are missing*" - then your embedded EXE is not self-contained to begin with, and thus you would have to distribute all of its dependent DLLs. In which case, using embedded resources is a bad choice (well, it is a bad idea to begin with), you should use a proper installer instead (MSI, InstallShield, Wise, etc), or even just a ZIP file. "*Should I install VS on the other laptop?*" - no. but you probably need the VC++ runtime. "*without any installation of any programs*" - then recompile the embedded EXE to static link everything and remove DLL dependencies.